# Cygwin terminal not displaying certain characters?

Tags: bash, encoding, cygwin, windows-1252, cp1252

I am running a stock Cygwin install, with the `wget` package added.

If I run a command

```
wget -qO- tetristv.com/zapni.tv.php
```

I get this; notice the incorrect display of characters

```
session=OTA5Mjc0ODU5OA==&stream=play</a></b><br>#EXTINF:0,▒T 1<br><b><a     
href="http://212.80.69.19/stream/vlc.php?id=39&session=OTA5Mjc0ODU5OA==&
stream=play" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">http://212.80.69.19/stream 
/vlc.php?id=39&session=OTA5Mjc0ODU5OA==&stream=play</a></b><br>#EXTINF:0,▒T 
2<br><b><a href="http://212.80.69.19/stream/vlc.php?id=40& 
session=OTA5Mjc0ODU5OA==&stream=play" target="_blank" 
rel="nofollow">http://212.80.69.19/stream/vlc.php?id=40&
session=OTA5Mjc0ODU5OA==&stream=play</a></b><br>#EXTINF:0,▒T 24<br><b><a
```

If I just download the file, everything looks fine in Notepad.

```
wget tetristv.com/zapni.tv.php
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$ LANG=en_US.CP1252
$ wget -qO- tetristv.com/zapni.tv.php
```

Result

```
261&session=NTk1NTg0ODU5OA==&stream=play</a></b><br>#EXTINF:0,Oèko<br><b><a
```

This also works

```
wget -qO- tetristv.com/zapni.tv.php | iconv -f cp1252
```

Comment: That means that the webpage isn't encoded in UTF-8, but CP1252.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using stock cygwin in Mintty and have my lang set as `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` and it's been working fine for me (unfortunately our proxy server is blocking the site you referenced so I can't test that). Check out [Internationalization](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/setup-locale.html) in the cygwin docs for more help.

**Edit:** verified that this UTF-8 views properly within mintty:

```
$ cat /d/temp/test.txt                                                                                                              
Creds Go here®
```

Comment: Are you using mintty or the modified cmd prompt? I just verified that I'm still properly seeing UTF-8 in mintty. I had a lot of problems getting the character set right in cmd.

Comment: Odd I know this works fine in Cyg (it used to drive me nutz when it didn't). Are you sure wget is pulling the file correctly?

Comment: @svnpenn: Go into the MinTTY options, under Text. Is "UTF-8" selected in the Character Set drop-down? Also, do you have a suitable font selected? I recommend either Lucida Console or DejaVu Sans Mono. Many otherwise good fonts don't have a suitably broad character set for use as a console font, particularly when you get into UTF-8 stuff.