# SED grabbing special characters

Tags: regex, sed, character-encoding

I’m trying to fix an encoding error in an archived html page. My problem is that sed is behaving strangely, as it doesn't catch special characters in the data. I tried both with and without -r switch.

My data is the following:
`Budapesti ??p?­t?©szeti Filmnapok k??l??nkiad??s`

The sed command:

`sed -i.bak 's|Budapesti.*|REPLACE|g' index.html`

and the result I get without recode:

`REPLACE�t?�szeti Filmnapok k??l??nkiad??s`

The result I'm expecting is:

`REPLACE`

It seems to be related to the encoding somehow. If I do `recode iso-8859-2 index.html` first, sed works fine and gets me the expected output.

Here are the hex bytes for the `i ??p?­t?Šs` part before recode:

`69 20 3F 3F 70 3F AD 74 3F A9 73`

and after recode:

`69 20 3F 3F 70 3F C2 AD 74 3F C5 A0 73`

BTW, this is what I get without recode:

`REPLACE­t?Šs`
`52 45 50 4C 41 43 45 AD 74 3F A9 73`

I'm using the latest gsed (GNU sed) 4.2.2.

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Your first command works for me.

Comment: It seems to be related to the encoding. I've added more information to the question, including a recode command and the hex code of the file at the problematic characters.

Comment: What if you say `sed -i.bak 's|Budapesti.*$|REPLACE|g' index.html
`? that is, to use `$` to indicate end of line.

Comment: @fedorqui: no diff in that case

Answer (score 1):

```
LANG=C.ISO-8859-2 sed -i.bak 's|Budapesti.*|REPLACE|g' index.html
```

[Cygwin terminal not displaying certain characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11050502/#11054050)

Comment: This one works fine, but why does sed stop on that 3F character without encoding set?

Comment: @zsero mine stops at AD, so not sure

Comment: I mean 3F is the last character which disappears and AD is the first one which stays.